# ItemsControl items positions issue

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

## Introduction

Hello!

I'm in the process of creating a custom WPF UserControl to display linked nodes (specifically for neural network visualization). I want to provide the UserControl's object source through data binding.

## Code

### XAML

```
<Grid Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}">
<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <!-- Node container -->
                <Canvas Background="AliceBlue"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding PosX}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding PosY}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <!-- The Node -->
                    <Ellipse Width="{Binding Radius}" Height="{Binding Radius}" Fill="{Binding BackColor}" />
                    <!-- Node Links -->
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Links}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Line Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"
                                            ToolTip="{Binding Tooltip}" 
                                            X1="{Binding SourceX}"      Y1="{Binding SourceY}"
                                            X2="{Binding DestinationX}" Y2="{Binding DestinationY}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel> </Grid>
```

### Csharp

```
public class StructureViewModel : BaseViewModel
{ 
    public double Width { get; set; } = 500;
    public double Height { get; set; } = 500;
    public List<Node> Items { get; set; }
    public Canvas SelectedShape { get; set; }

    public StructureViewModel()
    {
        Items = new List<Node>();

        var node1 = new Node(100, 150);
        var node2 = new Node(100, 180);
        node1.AddLink(node2);

        Items.Add(node1);
        Items.Add(node2);
    } 
}

public class Node : BaseViewModel
{
    public double Radius { get; set; } = 40;
    public Brush BackColor { get; set; } = Brushes.Blue;
    public double PosX { get; set; } = 0;
    public double PosY { get; set; } = 0;
    public List<Link> Links { get; set; }

    public Node(double posX, double posY)
    {
        Links = new List<Link>();
        PosX = posX;
        PosY = posY;
    }

    public Node(double posX, double posY, List<Link> links)
    {
        Links = links;
        PosX = posX;
        PosY = posY;
    }

    public void AddLink(Node node) => Links.Add(new Link(PosX, PosY, node.PosX, node.PosY)); 
}

public class Link : BaseViewModel
{
    public double SourceX { get; set; }
    public double SourceY { get; set; }
    public double DestinationX { get; set; }
    public double DestinationY { get; set; }
    public string ToolTip { get; set; }

    public Link(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, string tooltip = "")
    {
        SourceX = x1;
        SourceY = y1;
        DestinationX = x2;
        DestinationY = y2;
        ToolTip = tooltip;
    }   
}
```

The `BaseViewModel` implements the property change event through Fody Weaver.

## The issue

The Nodes and links are created as expected, although the **position of the linking line is incorrect**. The linking line is supposed to start from `node1` position and end at `node2` position.

## Tried but failed

I've tried setting the Style TargetType to the Canvas, Grid and other targets, but none worked. Creating a style for the Grid in the `DataTemplate` didn't help either.

## Wrapping up

Please help me solve this issue and most importantly better understand what I was doing wrong. Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Thank you!

Comment: "what I was doing wrong" - first you should make your ViewModel View-independent.